# connecting and inserting data into database with mysqli

Tags: php

I have been following some videos and other sources on how to connect to database. I am just new to programming and i can't  see where i have gone wrong with my connection. After heating the submit button on my form, the data seem to have been sent to database but after refreshing on my database, nothing is found. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my database connection code.

```
 <?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name  = 'student_registration';
$mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno){
    printf ("connect failed: %s/n", $mysqli -> connect_error);
    }
    else printf ("connected to database");

?>
```

Here is my insertion code.

```
<?php
require_once("opendb.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   

$department = $_POST['department'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$responsibility = $_POST['responsibility'];
$requirement = $_POST['requirement'];
$date=@"$_POST[year]"."-".@"$_POST[month]"."-".@"$_POST[day]";

$query = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('".$department."','".$post."','".$description."','".$responsibility."','".$requirement."','".$date."')";

$inset = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query );
if($inset){

          } 
?>
<script language="javascript">
alert("New Post Updated");
window.location="addpost.php";
</script>

<?php
} else{
 ?>
<script language="javascript">
alert("Post Updated did not update successfully Please try again");
window.location="addpost.php";
</script> 
 <?php 
 }
 ?>
```

The closing curly brace on if ($insert) is wrapping isset function. removing it renders the variables $department, $post etc as Unidentified variables.

Comment: try using error reporting with query execution. Like
`$inset = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query ) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));`

Comment: first of all have a look at php.net *how quoting is working*. hint at all it was never ever a good practice to suppress notices and warnings by using @ instead writing correct code

Answer (score 0):

Please SET PASSWORD for mysql database and then check. 
mysql was working well without password,

BUT mysqli WON'T WORK with blank password.

example::

for me,as I'm using lampp

/opt/lampp/bin/mysqladmin -uroot  password 'xyz'

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM #1:** Incorrect SQL Statement
You need to specify which column to add it to by listing the corresponding column names in the database and then matching the order for the variable names.
If your column names are:
`$department` is inserted into department column
`$post` is inserted into post column
Corrected Code:(Change the column names to your corresponding column names)

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO posts (department, post, description, responsiblity, requirement, date) VALUES ('$department','$post','$description','$responsibility','$requirement','$date')";
```

NOTE: Single quotations is enough for variables names in SQL statment

**PROBLEM #2:** $date Syntax Incorrect
Incorrect:

```
 $date=@"$_POST[year]"."-".@"$_POST[month]"."-".@"$_POST[day]";
```

There is no quotation around year, month or day. you need a quotation surrounding them. Assign each POST to a variable and use the variables If you're just trying to get the date use the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

**PROBLEM #3:** Major Security Issue
Using `mysqli_query` without any filtering is like saying HACK MY SERVER !
**Your database can easily be [SQL Injected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**
Using direct queries like this is insecure overall !! Please use [PHP prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) especially if this is a student registration form your planning to publish.

Comment: Thanks guys. i tried all suggested solutions but could not work still.